# GroupBy and then Sum

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to take the items from sortedItems and then create a GroupBy MaterialCode and MaterialThickness. Then I want to find the sum of NbrOfSheets where MaterialCode and MaterialThickness are the the same.

Here is my code.

```
var sortedItems =
db.Jobs
.Where(x => x.JobStatus == "O")
.OrderBy(x => x.Material.MaterialCode).ThenBy(x => x.MaterialThickness)
.ThenBy(x => x.IdealSheetSize).ThenByDescending(x => x.DueDate)
.Select(x => new
{
    x.JobNum,
    x.Material.MaterialCode,
    x.MaterialThickness,
    x.Part.CustPartNum,
    x.Part.CustName,
    x.IdealSheetSize,
    x.NbrOfSheets,
    x.DueDate,
    x.ShipmentNotes,
    JobRoutings = x.JobRoutings.Select(e => new
    {
        e.ProcessID,
        e.CrewSize,
        e.PiecesPerHour,
        e.OnHand,
        e.PC,
        e.LastScannedDate,
        e.OpSeq
    })
}).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: you've described your requirement but you forgot to tell us what your issue is in achieving it.

Comment: There's no GroupBy in your code

Comment: I am just having some trouble writing it

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know there is no GroupBy in the code. That's the part i am having trouble writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group by an anonymous type with these properties, then use `Sum` on the groups:

```
var result = sortedItems    
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.MaterialCode, x.MaterialThickness })
   .Select(g => new { 
       g.Key.MaterialCode, g.Key.MaterialThickness,
       NbrOfSheetsSum = g.Sum(x => x.NbrOfSheets)
    });
```

Comment: I am getting the error on NbrOfSheets "Cannot convert lambda expression to the intended delegate type"

Comment: @MattBrown: first you said that it worked. So what doesnt work now? What is your code? What type is `NbrOfSheets`?

Comment: NbrOfSheets is a string

Comment: @MattBrown: well, you can't sum a string. But why is it a string at all if it represents a count? You should change that, otherwise you always have to parse the string. `g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.NbrOfSheets))`

Answer (score 0):

I modeled your database with classes to get syntax correct.  See answer below :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase();

            var sortedItems =
                db.Jobs
                .Where(x => x.JobStatus == "O")
                .OrderBy(x => x.Material.MaterialCode).ThenBy(x => x.MaterialThickness).ThenBy(x => x.IdealSheetSize).ThenByDescending(x => x.DueDate)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.JobNum,
                    x.Material.MaterialCode,
                    x.MaterialThickness,
                    x.Part.CustPartNum,
                    x.Part.CustName,
                    x.IdealSheetSize,
                    x.NbrOfSheets,
                    x.DueDate,
                    x.ShipmentNotes,
                    JobRoutings = x.JobRoutings.Select(e => new
                    {
                        e.ProcessID,
                        e.CrewSize,
                        e.PiecesPerHour,
                        e.OnHand,
                        e.PC,
                        e.LastScannedDate,
                        e.OpSeq
                    })
                }).ToList();

            var groups = sortedItems.GroupBy(x => new { materialCode = x.MaterialCode, materialThickness = x.MaterialThickness })
                .Select(x => new { job = x, count = x.Sum(y => y.NbrOfSheets) }).ToList();


        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Job
    {
        public string JobStatus { get; set; }
        public Material Material { get; set; }
        public string MaterialThickness { get; set; }
        public string IdealSheetSize { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
        public int JobNum { get; set; }
        public Part Part { get; set; }
        public int NbrOfSheets { get; set; }
        public string ShipmentNotes { get; set; }
        public List<JobRoutings> JobRoutings { get; set; }
    }
    public class Material
    {
        public string MaterialCode { get; set; }
    }
    public class Part
    {
        public string CustPartNum { get; set; }
        public string CustName { get; set; }
    }
    public class JobRoutings
    {
        public string ProcessID {get;set;}
        public string CrewSize {get;set;}
        public string PiecesPerHour {get;set;}
        public string OnHand {get;set;}
        public string PC {get;set;}
        public string LastScannedDate {get;set;}
        public string OpSeq { get; set; }
    }
```